# Background, zombie, daemon and without ctty - are these concepts connected?

Tags: background-process, daemon, job-control, zombie-process, controlling-terminal

How these process concepts are related together - `background`, `zombie`, `daemon` and `without controlling terminal`?

I feel that they are somehow close, especially through the concept of `controlling terminal`, but there is still not much info for me to tell a story, like if you need to explain something to a child reading an article about Linux without lying too much.

**UPDATE #1: For example (I don't know if that's true)**

- `background` -- `zombie` - foreground process can not become `zombie`, because `zombie` is a background process that was left without a parent
- `daemon` -- `without ctty` - all `daemons` run without `ctty`, but not all processes without`ctty` are `daemons`
- `background` -- `daemon` - a `background process` can be retrieved to run interactively again, `daemon is not`
- `zombie` -- `without ctty` - `zombie` is indifferent if there is `ctty` attached to it or not
- `background` -- `without ctty` - `processes` sent to background while they have `ctty`, and become daemons or die if the `ctty` is taken from them

Comment: A foreground process can certainly be a zombie, although usually not for any appreciable period of time -- the usual way for a shell (or other program) to run a subprocess in the foreground is to `fork()` off a copy of yourself, use `exec()` in that copy to replace it with what you want to run, and use `wait()` in the original instance of program (not the copy that ran `exec()`). In the very, very short period of time between when the child exits and when the `wait()` reaps that exit status (removing it from the process table and returning it to the caller), you have a zombie.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is it possible to send parent to background while leaving child running in foreground?

Comment: In *typical* job control, the shell doesn't even know that the grandchild is separate from its direct child at all; it's just waiting for its child to exit, and if the child is waiting for a grandchild to exit, well, that's the child's business. Which is to say -- from the perspective of the shell that spawned the parent, it's only dealing with one unit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In brief, plus links.

### zombie

a process that has exited/terminated, but whose parent has not yet acknowledged the termination (using the `wait()` system calls). Dead processes are kept in the process table so that their parent can be informed that their child of the child process exiting, and of their exit status. Usually a program forking children will also read their exit status as they exit, so you'll see zombies only if the parent is stopped or buggy.

See:

- [Can a zombie have orphans? Will the orphan children be disturbed by reaping the zombie?](/q/248843)
- [How does Linux handle zombie processes?](/q/155012)
- [Linux man page `waitpid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

### controlling terminal, session, foreground, background

These are related to job control in the context of a shell running on a terminal. A user logs in, a session is started, tied to a terminal (the controlling terminal) and a shell is started. The shell then runs processes and sends them on the foreground and background as the user wishes (using `&` when starting the process, stopping it with `^Z`, using `fg` and `bg`).
Processes in the background are stopped if reading or writing from the terminal; processes in the foreground receive the interrupt signal if `^C` is hit on the terminal. (It's the kernel's terminal driver that handles those signals, the shell controls which process (group) is sent to the foreground or background.

See:

- [Difference between nohup, disown and &](/q/3886)
- [Bash reference manual: Job Control Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html)

### daemon

A process running as a daemon is usually something that shouldn't be tied to any particular terminal (or a login session, or a shell). It shouldn't have a controlling terminal, so that it won't receive signals if the terminal closes, and one usually doesn't want it to do I/O on a terminal either. Starting a daemon from the command line requires breaking all ties to the terminal, i.e. starting a new session (in the job control sense, above) to get rid of the controlling terminal, and closing the file handles to the terminal. Of course something started from `init`, systemd or similar outside a login session wouldn't have these ties to begin with.

Since a daemon doesn't have a controlling terminal, it's not subject to job control, and being in the "foreground" or "background" in the job control sense doesn't apply. Also, daemons usually re-parent to `init` which cleans them as they exit, so you don't usually see them as zombies.

See:

- [What's the difference between running a program as a daemon and forking it into background with '&'?](/q/56495)
- [Linux man page `daemon(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here is my explanation with a stress on *differences* between these types of processes (short yet informative):

- `zombie` - process that has just exited (finished it's execution) but still has an entry in a process table. **Note**: *zombie* process still has a *parent* and usually the whole point of it's existence is to let that parent process know about the result of child's execution (exit code etc.).
- `disowned process` (without controlling terminal) - process that was either explicitly `disown`'ed by user or designed to be detached from a parent process tree. It would still run even if the parent process would finish execution. For example, user `ssh`'ed to a remote machine, started something like a web server, then run `disown` on it and exited from `ssh` session. The process would still be running as it's not a part of a parent process tree anymore. Process also can be disowned running it with `nohup`.
- `background process` - runs in a background - doesn't split output to a user's tty. Either was run with `&` in the end, or forked itself to a background by design. Other option to send a process to a background is to start it and press `ctrl+z`. Yet, when the parent process will terminate, the child running in a background would also terminate (**note** by @psusi - the prior fact is only true with processes started from a terminal by user; otherwise child process becomes an 'orphant' and gets an init process (pid 1) as a parent).

  - `daemon` - very similar to the background process. Also runs in a background but most probably was forked implicitly (by design). Usually it sits quietly in a background waiting for some even occur and only then does an actual work (incoming connection etc). Actually, *daemon* can be both *disowned* (more probably) and *background* process depending on it's design.

Hope this explanation would help to distinguish these types of processes.

Comment: Nice. Process table belongs to parent? So zombies die without their master?

Comment: Table is not a right word. It's rather a process `tree`. Yes, sure, parent is not bounded to terminate after it's child terminated (but it can do so if it was waiting for a child to finish processing of some sort of stuff). But if parent would terminate - child would terminate definitely. You can run `top` from your terminal and then press `shift-v` to see process trees in a wild.

Comment: A parent terminating does not kill its children.  The orphaned children have their parent process ID changed to init ( 1 ).

Comment: @psusi you're right, I forgot that it's so only with processes started in terminal. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: I would just remove the "it would disappear from a table soon" sentence. It suggest that it somehow automatically fades away after some time, but that is not the case; the "disappearing" is a very concrete event.

Answer (score 4):

**Zombie** isn't really related to the others; it simply is a process that has terminated, but its parent process has not yet read its exit status with `waitpid()` or similar.  You shouldn't see these unless a process is buggy or stopped.

A **daemon** is a program that runs without a controlling terminal.  Typically when you run the program, it `fork()s` itself, and the parent exits so the shell thinks the command has finished, and the child process detaches from the terminal and escapes the login session.  Since its parent process exited, its parent process ID becomes 1, which is traditionally the `init` program, or these days, `systemd`.  This process makes sure to reap its children when they die so you don't end up overrun with zombies.

A process can be associated with a **controlling terminal**, which is where it normally gets its input from and sends its output to.  The terminal also can send signals to processes attached to it, and identifies a process group as the **foreground group**.  Processes that are in the **foreground group** are allowed to read input from the terminal, and are sent SIGINT and SIGSUSP signals when you press Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z.  Any process not in the **foreground group** that tries to read from the terminal is suspended with SIGTSTP.

The shell creates different process groups for each of the pipeline commands you ask it to run, and shifts which one is the **foreground group** to move jobs between the foreground and background.  When you run a command, normally the shell makes a new process group and makes that group the **foreground group**.  If you suffix it with an `&` then the shell simply leaves the **foreground group** where it was  and so the new group is in the background.  Pressing Ctrl-Z sends SIGSUSP to the foreground group, which causes most commands to suspend, but instead of suspending, the shell changes the active **foreground group** back to itself so it can prompt you for a new command.

The `bg` command sends SIGCONT to a process group so that it can resume running in the background after having been suspended with SIGSUSP.  `fg` changes the **foreground group** to one of the existing groups already running in the background, bringing it to the foreground.